# Setting High and Low Limit for Inventory

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, limits

So I am running into some trouble with VBA. I have been working on an inventory project, and just as I am about to complete it I was thrown an additional task involving VBA. I am very inexperienced with VBA, so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

```
Unfortunately, I cannot post actual pictures of the inventory sheets, so I will make a mock-up. The actual quantities of the items are in column G, starting at row 10 down to row 2084. 

Example: 2 8 4 13 29 29 38 55 8 75.
```

What my customer wants is to set a high and low limit of the inventory quantities with a VBA script. The requested parameters are as follows:

```
**Low Limit:** 
IF value is 10 or less - set low limit to 10;
IF value is between 10 and 30 - set low limit to 10;
IF value is 30 or greater - set low limit to 30;

**High Limit:** 
50% more than what each value is, rounded to the nearest whole number, unless that value is 10 or below. In which case the high limit would be 15, since the low limit of those values is set to 10.
```

The inventory quantities that I currently have are the initial quantities. These quantities will be changed as things are removed/added to the inventory. However, these initial quantities are what is going to be used as a baseline for the high/low limits. So my thought is that the initial quantities need to be stored into an array and those initial quantities in the array are what will be used to calculate the high/low limits, even when the inventory is updated. If that is not possible I will just add an initial inventory column to the spreadsheet, but it is a fixed template, so they would prefer that I not do that.

Additionally, after running the VBA script to determine the high/low limits, I would like the individual quantity cells to turn red if that value is under the low limit and blue if the value is above the high limit. Obviously, the first time that it is run, there will be no values that are above the high limit because those values will be used to calculate the high limits. However, all the quantities that are initially below 10 will have their cells turn red because they are starting out below their defined low limit.

I know that this is a lot, but any help would be appreciated as I'm not sure where to start. Thank you!!

Comment: I don't get what you want to achive... You described (as I think) very easy problem. Can you describe shortly what is your problem and goal?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I made everything clear. At any given time, the customer wants to be able to run the VBA script to see which items in the inventory are above the high limit and below the low limit. The cells should turn red if below the low limit and blue if above the high limit. However, the limits are calculated using the initial inventories. So the quantities will change but the high/low limits for each item will stay the same. Does that help clarify?

Comment: I apologize if it is a very simple solution, I am just a novice when it comes to VBA.

Comment: With this low limit I understand, but with high limit is something wrong... If first appear value is reference value for high limit, so for ex. 2 - set it to 5. Now it is in low limit (<10) and in high limit (>3)...

Comment: For numbers that are 10 or less, the high value would be set to 15

Comment: sounds like something you could do with conditional formatting and a custom function

Comment: That is what I plan to try if I cannot figure out a VBA script. However, they specifically wanted a VBA script to tackle this problem, so I will try that avenue first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you need.

If you want to save highlimit on initial values, you need to create new sheet call it for ex. Config and with using normal excel function create high limit values. (In Sheet1 I create list of your examples values)

```
=ROUND(IF(Sheet1!A1<=10; 15;Sheet1!A1*1,5);0)
```

Then you need to copy this cells and paste only values in Config instead formulas.

Here you have code which does what you want.

```
Private Sub prcCheckLimits()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim wsHighLimit As Worksheet: Set wsHighLimit = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Config")
    Dim lngRow As Long 'lastRow
    Dim i As Long

    lngRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lngRow
        With ws
            If .Cells(i, 1).value < fncLowLimit(.Cells(i, 1).value) Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf .Cells(i, 1).value > wsHighLimit.Cells(i, 1).value Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            Else
                .Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function fncLowLimit(value As Long) As Long
    Dim result As Long

    If value < 30 Then
        result = 10
    Else
        result = 30
    End If

    fncLowLimit = result
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you!! So the high limit values need to be pasted into where it says "Config" ?

Comment: Yes. You need to remember, that values in Config should corespond with values in Sheet1. If this is your solution, please mark it with green tick on the left from answer.